firebase auth failed with aab version (flutter)
I have published my Flutter app on the Google Play Console and set it up for closed testing. I provided the testing link to my testers, but they are experiencing issues where certain functions, such as logging in, do not work as expected. However, when I download and install the APK directly, everything works fine.

Is it auth through some provider like Google or Apple, or just Username and Password?

Please ask the user to send you a screen shot, without further info, no one can assist you.
Anyway, I had similar issues while testers trying to log in 'user not found'. it works after a few attempts. I am assuming firebase server have issues when you share the same username to multiple users for testing.

To fix the issue, ensure your API keys and environment configurations match the Play Console build. Check Proguard/R8 settings to prevent essential code from being stripped. Verify app signing settings and ensure testers are added correctly in the closed testing group. Finally, review logs for more details on the problem.
